# Does the Server exe or Server jar file for minecraft 1.0.0 still exist?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I want to host a private SMP for Minecraft 1.0.0 as we wanted to beat the game with old standards. I dont seem to find the .jar file or .exe file for the server. Some people said It was on the 1.0.0 wiki, but there wasn't a downloadable file to be found. Are there any archive sites where I could find it? I've went to mcversions.net or mctimemachine.com but none of them work at all. Hopefully there's an archive where I could download em

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As you mentioned, you can download the Minecraft 1.0.0's server's jar file (and .exe file) from fandom, it is found at [Java Edition 1.0.0 page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.0.0), screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of Minecraft fandom]

Click your Right Mouse Button and select `Save link as...` (or whatever it's called on your browser) and select a location to save, and the file will be downloaded at the selected location.